# How could I find the $35$th derivative of this rational function?

Tags: calculus

I am struggling to find the $35$th derivative of $f(x)$ where

$$f(x)={1+x^{34}(x+3)^3(x+1)\over x^2(x+9)+27(x+1)}$$

Comment: I'm going to start with what is hopefully an obvious question: Why?!?

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: @ConMan This was a question on a past test for one of my calculus classes. I want to make sure I can do it to prepare myself for the test.

Comment: @Null I don't know where to begin...

Comment: It's a good idea to explain where the question comes from to start with, in general. The reason being that that can affect where you look for an answer. In this case, "question on a test" suggests that there's a trick, such as a nice factorisation you can make use of (which is the case here). "It came from trying to do something else" is often a candidate for "maybe there's a better approach to the real problem".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:**
Notice that your denominator is$$(x+3)^3$$
Then $f(x)$ can be rewritten as
$$f(x)=\frac{1+x^{34}(x+3)^3(x+1)}{x^2(x+9)+27(x+1)}=\frac{1+x^{35}(x+3)^3+x^{34}(x+3)^3}{(x+3)^3}$$
And then your entire expression can be reduced to $$x^{35}+x^{3
4}+\frac{1}{(x+3)^3}$$
I guess now it's easy to find $n$th derivatives of these terms easily

**Note 1 :**

$$\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} x^n = n!$$

Don't see this unless you've solved it yourself

> $$\large\frac{\mathrm d^{35}}{\mathrm dx^{35}}f(x) =35!+0-\frac{37!}{2(x+3)^{38}}$$

Comment: In general, the $k^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $x^n$ will be 
   $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} x^{n-k}$$

Comment: @Nick Not really, Someday I'm surely gonna reach $2K$!

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed that the denominator could be factorized in that way. After you realize that the question becomes smooth sailing. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: factorise the denominator, then simplify the expression for $f(x)$ to get. . .

> $$f(x)=x^{35}+x^{34}+\dfrac1{(x+3)^3}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed that the denominator could be factorized in that way. After you realize that the question becomes smooth sailing. Thanks again for your help.